# Django cannot render model attributes by slug to the template

Tags: python, django

I have set a model including some attributes and can get the model by a slug in views.py. However, I can't render its attributes into the template. Did I miss something?

Model.py

```
class article(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
content = RichTextUploadingField()
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Views.py

```
def post_details(request, slug):
 details = get_object_or_404(article, slug=slug)
 context = {
    details: 'details'
 }
 return render(request, 'post_details.html', context)
```

Urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.home, name='home'),
  path('<slug:slug>/', views.post_details, name='post_details')
]
```

I have set a URL to get the article model's data by slug in index.html

```
<h4 class="title"><a href="{% url 'post_details' article.slug %}">{{ article.title }}</a></h4>
```

post_details.html

```
<h2>{{ details.slug }}</h2>
```

I can access this template by slug but can't get any attributes by using the 'details' tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the key: value the wrong way around in your `context` dict in `views.py`:

```py
context = {
    details: 'details'
 }

# should be:
context = {
    'details': details
}
```

Your version has a dict with key of the actual model instance, pointing to a value of the string `"details"`, which is the opposite of what you want :-)

it "works" (doesn't cause an error) because templates silently ignore missing keys/attributes when accessing context variables.

There's a special setting [`string_if_invalid`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables) that you can set on your template configuration to make it more obvious when a var isn't present, although as it mentions, you can't really leave it enabled all the time since lots of other code expects this silent empty-string behaviour.